# Inverting a generic constraint

Tags: c#

I've been heavily learning generic constraints the last week. While learning them more in depth, I became curious if it's possible to invert them in some way. The people I work with aren't sure that such a thing exists and my google searching has also come up with nothing.

The closest answer I got was to use struct instead of class, but while I can see why the person thought this was a decent answer and would work for most of the uses, it still doesn't answer if there is a way of inverting the constraint.

Does anyone else know if it's possible to invert a constraint?

e.g.

```
class myClass<T> where T: !class
{
}
```

Comment: `where T: !class` can be said as `where T: struct` ... why such inversion notation needed at all?

Comment: @Rahul - This is probably just an example. A constraint can also be an interface, for example.

Comment: @Rahul read the second paragraph

Comment: @Kobi, yes it can but in any case the negation symbol not needed. `!constraint` can be said as absence of that constraint just

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such syntax in C#.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

> The following table lists the six types of constraints:
>
> **where T: struct**    The type argument must be a value type.
> Any value type except Nullable can be specified. See Using Nullable
> Types for more information. where T : class   The type argument must be
> a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate,
> or array type.
>
> **where T : new()**    The type argument must have a public
> parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints,
> the new() constraint must be specified last.
>
> **where T : (base class name)**    The type argument must be or derive from the specified base
> class.
>
> **where T : (interface name)**     The type argument must be or
> implement the specified interface. Multiple interface constraints can
> be specified. The constraining interface can also be generic.
>
> **where T : U**    The type argument supplied for T must be or derive from the
> argument supplied for U.

So there is no option to say **where T is any type other than U**

Think about it this way - suppose you had

```
class myClass<T> where T: !string
{
}
```

You know `T` is not a string, but *you have no other indication of what `T` might be*.  So how do you code against it? These would all be valid delcarations:

```
var x1 = new myClass<int>();
var x2 = new myClass<object>();
var x3 = new myClass<DateTime>();
var x4 = new myClass<DataTable>();
```

What code could you have that applies to all of these types, but would be invalid for `string`?